# Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'time.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php

Tags: php, upload

I've found those warnings after uploading my website on a free host server hostinger:

> Warning: include_once(neabat.pe.hu/admin/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 5

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'neabat.pe.hu/admin/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 5

Warning: include_once(time.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 6

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'time.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 6

Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.2.1.23' (using password: NO) in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 10
mysql_erro

I've spent many days so far & still don't know what's the wrong with my code
Please any help for how to overcome this problem! Many thanks in advance

Comment: We don't know what is wrong with ***your code*** either, since we have no idea what ***your code*** looks like.

Comment: You don't include from the domain, you include from the server root. So it would look something like `include "/home/u751914102/public_html/admin/config.php";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these errors....

> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.2.1.23' (using password: NO) in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 10 mysql_erro

...try replacing the `mysql_query()` clause with 'mysqli_query()' in your code. `mysql_query()` is currently not supported (deprecated) for your case.

For these errors....

> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'neabat.pe.hu/admin/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include_once(time.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 6
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'time.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 6

...you gonna have to install and configure `pear` correctly.
UNFORTUNATELY, [you CANNOT install pearl/pear extensions in hostinger servers!](http://www.hostinger.ph/knowledge-base/232.html)

Comment: Why would replacing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` work when we don't know which API he's really using? You can't mix APIs, and it just stated that `mysql_` is old and will be removed, not that it *is* removed. The connection-errors is probably because his includes fail.

Comment: Simply because it is stated clearly on the error log: `Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u751914102/public_html/scripts/head.php on line 10`

Comment: If his entire code is lined around `mysql_`, it certainly would not help to swap his query to `mysqli_`, he'd have to swap *everything* to `mysqli_`, becasue you **can't** mix APIs (which frankly is a very good idea, but we don't know what API he is using, most likely it's `mysql_` as there are several markers to `mysql_query()`). His error-log did *not* state that he should swap his query only, the deprecated message is default for any `mysql_` function. They still work, but is removed in PHP 7 (which I doubt he's using, he would've gotten other warnings).